# Prioritise gRPC calls to avoid server overload

Tags: c++, grpc

I'm using gRPC to gather scene nodes tree, properties or other resources from server. All communication is asynchronous.
Nodes tree calls are send after parent response arrive for each of it child. So amount of request sent grows quite quickly. For tree with 1500-2000 nodes in total there're times when other calls (like properties) waits for 5-10 sec to be processed. 
One of idea is to use priorities or second queue on client side. Does gRPC provides priorities? How in gRPC can I limit amount of calls 'in-air' at given time? If you could point me to code examples (C++) how this problem is or can be solved - I would be much obliged.

Answer (score 0):

There is no priority that you can set for gRPC calls. If you want to limit the amount of calls to a particular channel, you may set the channel arg [GRPC_ARG_MAX_CONCURRENT_STREAMS](https://github.com/grpc/grpc/blob/master/include/grpc/impl/codegen/grpc_types.h#L150) when you creates the channel.